# Executing a controller in global.asax which has area and dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, global-asax

I am trying to execute a controller from `global.asax`. The controller sits in the root controller folder but the error happens within a controller that is inside an area within the web application. Below is the `global.asax` code:

```
protected override void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "error";
    routeData.Values["exception"] = ex;
    routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
    routeData.Values["ErrorCode"] = 503;

    IController controller = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext, "Error");
    controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(context), routeData));
}
```

and here is the error I am getting:

```
The controller for path '/1985-books/usa/3rhvasdfasfd' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

**UPDATE:**

This code worked perfectly when the controllers are not in the `area`, once I use this code in situation that controller which the error happens at, this error happens. I have a feeling by default it is looking for `Error` which is in the root directory and once it becomes a little complicated `Error` written in `uest.RequestContext, "Error");` cannot find the correct route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add a call to `Server.ClearError` first, so that it knows that you are handling the error in a custom way:

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // capture the exception beforehand  if you need to
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        // Tell the server we're handling the error "our way"
        Server.ClearError();
        ...
        // You may also need to reset the response type
        Context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(context), routeData));
    }
```

### Update

Try using the RequestContext you create, when you are attempting to construct the controller in the first place:

```
var requestContext = new RequestContext(
    new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
IController controller = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory()
    .CreateController(requestContext, "Error");
controller.Execute(requestContext);
```

Comment: that is already in place. I just didnt add it here so that it doesnt confuse people. again for the controllers that are sitting in the root directory, works perfectly, only doesnt work for the controllers that are in the area section.

Comment: @user3311522: Try reusing the `requestContext`, as I show in my update, rather than relying on the `HttpContext.Current`.